# Start application with specific name from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have application with the following name: `"x64.Staging.1.0.0.99.ClientBootstrapper"`. I need install this app every week. From powershell i use this command

```
"./x64.Staging.1.0.0.99.ClientBootstrapper"
```

but every week version the version number changes and I have to change the my script. How I can update my script so that the script will automatically detect the latest version of the application and run it ?
I tried using the following:

```
$version=“x64.Staging.{0-9}.ClientBootstrapper.exe
./x64.Staging.$version.ClientBootstrapper.exe /qn
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially do the following:

```
$exe = Get-ChildItem -Path "x64.Staging.[0-9]*.ClientBootstrapper.exe" -File | Sort-Object {
    [version]($_.Name -replace 'x64\.Staging\.([0-9\.]+)\.ClientBootstrapper\.exe','$1' -replace '^\d+$','$0.0')
} -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1 | Resolve-Path -Relative
& $exe '/qn'
```

**Explanation:**

The strategy is to sort by the version string in the middle of the filename. `-replace` removes all characters in the file name except the version. `([0-9\.]+)` matches one or more digits and dots. `$1` is the capture group that represents the version string. Since a version object requires at least a major and minor number (`3.2` for example), a `.0` is appended to a lone, single digit that may show up in the version string.

`Resolve-Path` is just to return the relative path. It is not necessary as you could remove the command and then modify `Select-Object -First 1 -Expand FullName`